# Is it possible to open my application from iMessage app link?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app where you can have your favorite restaurant listed and add their details like name,image,comment,rating,etc. 
 Now I need to support a feature of share restaurant what I am doing right now is I am storing the data to Firebase so that data can be shared. 
  What I would like to do is I want to create a link for the same.. which will be sent in the iMessage when clicked on share button and then when the person with whom I shared my restaurant detail clicks on the link in the iMessage I want to open the app in his device ? 
 So that I can load data of the restaurant from firebase and show them in the app.

P.S. the app is actually offline that is not storing on the server. Just to support the above feature I am sending data to firebase. so that I can retrieve   it !

Comment: I would suggest you look at [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/). That way the user will see your app on the App Store if they don’t have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase dynamic links for that:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/?authuser=0

You can also send some parameters in the dynamic link.